Understanding the proof that irreducible polynomial over $K$ is factors into $2$ irreducible polynomial
Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ with $[K : \mathbb Q] = 2$. Let $P \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $P$
is either irreducible in $K[x]$ or splits as product of two irreducible polynomials in $K[x]$.
Assume that $P$ is reducible in $K[x]$. Let $g$ be an irreducible factor of $P$ in $K[x]$. $\alpha$ is root of $g$.
The hint I got that is, It suffices to show that
$\deg g = (\deg P)/2$.
First we can show if polynomial is reducible over $K$ then degree of $P$ is even ,
Which is easy to show(because degree of extension is $2$)
$[K(\alpha) : K][K : \mathbb{Q}] = [K(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = [K(\alpha) :\mathbb{Q} (\alpha)][ \mathbb{Q} (\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}],$
so $2 \deg g = (\deg P)[K(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)].$ Since $\deg g  \lt \deg P$, it follows that $[K(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \lt 2$ so
$[K(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 1$. Hence $\deg g = (\deg P)/2$
Now why  $\deg g = (\deg P)/2$ is sufficient to show.

The "hazard" is that $g = P$ or $g$ is a constant.  Can you show that neither of these is possible, so that $P/g$ is another polynomial that is neither constant nor $P$?

Yes that's easy it will be irreducible over $K$ then and it doesn't factor but the question is saying if it factors over $K$ it will be two irreducible factors.

It's sufficient to show $\deg g = \frac {\deg P}{2}$ because the proof works for all irreducible factors of $P$.  How many irreducible factors can $P$ have with degree exactly $\frac {\deg P}{2}$?

Yes it will be two but it is only shown for 1 irreducible factor how to show that other factor would be irreducible.

If the other factor were reducible, then it would have irreducible factors, which also would be irreducible factors of $P$ with degree strictly smaller than $\frac{\deg P}{2}$.  But you've just shown that any irreducible factor of $P$ has to have degree $\frac{\deg P}{2}$.
$$$$
By the way, you've never defined $\alpha$ in your question.  What is it?

$\alpha $ is root of $g$.

Let $g$ be an irreducible factor of $P$. Then, $\deg g=\frac12\deg P$. Consider $P/g$, a factor of $P$. Note that $\deg(P/g)=\frac12\deg P$. Let $h$ be an irreducible factor of $P/g$, what can you say about $h$? (I have the answer in spoilers below, open once you have tried enough!)

 $h$ is an irreducible factor of $P$, so $\deg h=\frac12\deg P$. Hence, $h=P/g$. Thus, $P=gh$, where $g$ and $h$ are irreducible.

Hope this helps. :)
